# How to disable user to input readonly Jquery Datepicker field by button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

my Datepicker field has a button for user to choose date. However, when I try to disable and set readonly on this field, the button still working!

Here is how I setup:
HTML

```
<input name="ResponseDate" type="text" value="15/02/2017" readonly="readonly" id="ResponseDate" disabled="disabled" class="txtInput dateSelector hasDatepicker">
```

JavaScript

```
 $(".dateSelector").datepicker({
                duration: "fast",
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                constrainInput: true,
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonText: 'Select Date',
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonImage: "../IMAGE/dayPick.png"
            });
```

The result of my setup will show a disabled input field with a button. User can still choose date by clicking that button although the input field  is readonly and disabled.

How can I disable that button with no any editing with JavaScript?

Comment: try this `$("#buttonID").attr("disabled",true);`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by this: "How can I disable that button with no any editing with JavaScript?" But the best way to disable that button is adding one line after you set the datepicker as shown below:

```
$( ".dateSelector" ).datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
```

Comment: Updated my answer...try that instead

Answer (score 0):

I think the datepicker is re-declaring and re-setting the input field attributes.

Add this line of code after the datepicker:

$( '.dateSelector' )
.attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' )
.attr( 'readonly', 'readonly' );

Or

$( '.dateSelector' )
.prop( 'disabled', 'disabled' )
.prop( 'readonly', 'readonly' );

However, I'm sure the former should work it just fine.